# Zoom and Transparant Color Overlay Mouseover CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have this piece of code where it's zooming in the image on cursor hover. However, I do also wish to add a transparent color overlay in `RGB` or `Hex`, how can I add this to the following code?

```
.hover-zoom-in .fl-photo-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hover-zoom-in .fl-photo-content .fl-photo-img {
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
          transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  will-change: transform;
}
.hover-zoom-in .fl-photo-content .fl-photo-img:hover {
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
          transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Mitrch: for better understanding provide your html

Comment: What are your efforts in achieving the desired results?

Comment: @wasim Sayyed: exactly the same thing i mean

Comment: OP just provided current css and asking us to write code, I am asking what are OP's efforts **IN CSS** to achieve it and not HTML

Comment: @Wasim Sayyed: yeah, but if posting the questions it not enough for the achieving solutions they should fully elaborate.

Comment: Ok understood but one can understand the situation from CSS also, like below answer by @Joykal

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
}
.outer .image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.outer .image img {
  width: 500px;
}
.outer .image::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  content: '';
}
.outer .image:hover {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.outer .image:hover::before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/242ce817-97a3-48fe-9acd-b1bf97930b01/09-posterization-opt.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering that is exactly what I'm looking fr. Only its still not showing the color hover. Can you take a look at my answer:) Thank you so much!